# Access two different Jupyter while running multiple VM's

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I'm running two VM's on GCP at the same time. The access to jupyter notebook is through 'http://localhost:8080/lab?' but how do I acess two different jupyter notebooks? (The adress mentioned in both VM's is the same))

Comment: I don't know that much about Jupyter configs, but `localhost` is just the hostname of the machine's loopback interface (and is the same on every machine -- so of course both VMs see the same name).  This isn't likely to be the way to access the notebook remotely, which would need to be listening on an external interface of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access multiple notebooks being hosted on different VM's you will need to ensure that you assign an external IP address to the VM hosting the notebook.

There is a good tutorial on how exactly to set up GCP VM's hosting Jupyter notebooks [Running Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud Platform](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52). When completed you would then use the following URL to access;

```
http://<External Static IP Address>:<Port Number>
```